# Feynman diagrams vs old fashioned peturbation theory (OFPT) vs reality

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, perturbation-theory

As far as I understand, our best picture of the world is that it is comprised of universe-spanning fields (one for each type of particle) that can interact with each other. The interactions are local, so if a field 'feels' a potential at point $x_0$, the potential can only depend on the values and derivatives of other fields evaluated at the point $x_0$ (I hope I am making sense). So, in effect, a field can 'deposit' some of its energy at point $x_0$ into another field, so long as its allowed to by symmetry laws and charges and such.

The Feynman diagram picture sounds much the same. We imagine particles meeting up (at the exact same point in space?), interact, then some product particles come out at the other end, but this time we sum all the possible ways the interaction could occur, even involving fields that didn't necessarily show up in the input or output states. I've been told that this summation cannot be interpreted as real, since the virtual particles participating do not obey their equations of motion, so they cannot exist in the real world. Feynman diagrams are just mathematical fiction that helps us calculate. And of course, the summation of diagrams is infinite, and an infinitude of different things can't happen at the same point at the same time in reality, according to my intuition at least.

Okay, now OFPT. In chapter 4 of Schwartz, he says you can calculate the transition rates from an initial state $|\phi_i\rangle$ to a final state $|\phi_f\rangle$ with the equation
$$
\langle\phi_f|T|\phi_i\rangle =
\langle\phi_f|V|\phi_i\rangle +
\langle\phi_f|V\frac{1}{E - H_0}|\phi_j\rangle\langle\phi_j|V|\phi_i\rangle + \cdots,\tag{4.11}
$$
i.e., another infinite sum. He states that the difference between this and Feynman diagrams is that all the states (initial, final, intermediate) are physical and on-shell, but do not conserve energy at vertices.

I don't understand what makes OFPT something different from mathematical fiction. We still have an infinite sum, we don't have energy conservation which is normally rather important in real physical processes. Is OFPT an honest description of what is really happening in particle interactions? And if not, do we have any mathematical models that describes particle interactions in the way it is described in my first paragraph?

Answer (score 12):

> I don't understand what makes OFPT something different from mathematical fiction.

It's not a mathematical fiction because it gives correct results.  That is *the* thing that separates physical theories that are true from those that are not.  Principles like energy conservation are "true" instead of "fiction" because they make experimental predictions which are true.  If you have a calculation scheme (i.e. a theory) which does not respect energy conservation manifestly at vertices, like OFPT, but still ends up with predictions that have it in all the places where we end up seeing it, which OFPT manages to do, then there are no problems and it is correct.  The Feynman diagram way ends up being the way that everyone thinks about these problems, though, because it's easier to calculate with, manifestly covariant, and conceptually a cleaner way to think about renormalization and infinities.

Schwartz covers the calculational details on both sides pretty well, and he says in the intro to that chapter that Dyson and friends showed in the 50s that both ways of doing the calculation end up with the same results, so which one is correct is no longer a question of physics.  The characters and objects that show up in theories and the way that we manipulate them can be suggestive to our imaginations in ways that jive with our intuitions or don't at all, and this is important for the actual process of doing physics, where you make guesses and follow hunches and play with the theories that you have to figure out what's wrong with them.  But you have to remember *a physical theory is a machine which predicts the results of experiments,* and in the end, the only thing that counts as physics is quantitative prediction.

Comment: Feynman Diagrams also give the correct results, yet I've often heard them described as mathematical fiction. Isn't it worth differentiating between reality and the picture our mathematical models give us? The Earth can be modelled as a point in space with gravity equal to the sum of gravities of its constituent particles, but of course the Earth isn't that.

Comment: I would like to add, to the first couple of sentences of this answer, [these 10 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYPapE-3FRw) from a lecture by Feynman.

Comment: @Depenau Feynman diagrams and OFPT are equally fictional.  Feynman diagrams are more convenient.  The difference between the Earth in space is that Feynman diagrams/OFPT (in QED, where we're best at calculating) are correct as far as we can tell experimentally—you can measure the Earth's deviation from being a point all sorts of ways. There are some quirks, either theoretical or experimental (e.g. the QED Landau pole, muon g-2, etc.) that tell us that our theory isn't complete, but  it is eminently clear that the QFT is the framework in which our physical theories must live (until GR...)

Answer (score 12):

Feynman Diagrams and OFPT are both quantitative tools for determining the things we actually can measure from quantum field theory - transition probabilities between states.  By this I mean we expand the states of a QFT in a convenient basis of particle occupation number $\{|n_{p_1},\dots\rangle\}$ and then we can ask what the amplitude for some particular state to evolve to another one is.  When we do this we end up with a perturbation series in the interaction terms of the Hamiltonian which is, through various sets of machinery and theorems, then interpreted as Feynman Diagrams.  (An interesting historical note is that this is quite different from how Feynman himself came up with the diagrams, which was via a mixture of intuition and his path integral approach to QM.  It wasn't until Freeman Dyson came up with the perturbative interpretation of them that they became the primary way to discuss QFT.)

As for what "really happens" in the interaction, this is not something we can answer.  In quantum theories you only ever observe eigenstates of the operator you are interested in and asking what happened between the emitter and detector (at least with our current model of nature) is a matter of philosophy.  Feynman diagrams are a useful tool that makes the calculation of correlation functions in QFT considerably simpler than OFPT but they should not be taken literally; the only thing we can say for certain is what the distribution of final states in an experiment looks like and whether or not that agrees with our models.  However, they certainly are an easy way to orient yourself and develop some kind of picture of what is going on, so much so that [some very knowledgable physicists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Representation_of_physical_reality) have believed that a diagrammatic language, while derived from perturbation theory, may be more inherent to reality than QFT.

As a final aside I would like to mention an incredibly important theoretical tool: the Feynman path integral.  In this formalism for quantum theory we think of amplitudes as a sum over all field configurations exponentially weighted by their action (in QM this is all paths), including those which do not satisfy the classical equations of motion.  This is why the internal lines in Feynman diagrams do not have to satisfy $E^2=p^2+m^2$ as that is enforced by the classical equations of motion in field theory.  So, while our (non-interacting) Hamiltonian eigenstates *do* satisfy this relation, and thus we always measure particles with the correct energy-momentum relation, the path integral gives some more reasoning why the perturbation series seems to include intermediate off-mass shell states.  Further, the path integral makes clear the incorporation of *non-perturbative* effects as well.  These are interactions which the perturbation series completely misses that have important consequences for the possible physics of the theory.  An example of a non-perturbative effect in QM is the famous tunneling that occurs in double well problems, while the archetypal example in QFT are [instantons in Yang-Mills theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton).

Comment: Why is "the state evolves according to the Schrödinger equation" not an adequate answer to what happens between the emitter and the detector?

Comment: @KrisWalker One answer is because the state is not an observable — it is something we never have experimental access to. How then can we say anything definite about it?

Comment: Another answer is because the Schrödinger is fundamentally nonrelativistic, so it cannot describe relativistic processes very well.  If you try to shoehorn them in, you can come up with a Hamiltonian that can model the leading relativistic perturbations to $p^2/2m$, but when $m \sim p$ the series breaks down and you really should be doing field theory.

Schwartz Ch 22 is on non-renormalizable theories, including a section looking at the Schrödinger equation from this perspective.

Comment: @gabe The state is not an observable but it determines the distribution of the observables, which is the thing we actually care about in scattering experiments. You can't compare the probabilistic result of a single measurement to theory. That's why we perform measurements on ensembles of systems with identical initial conditions to obtain amplitudes. Verifying the predictions of scattering theory relies on the state being experimentally accessible.

Comment: @RokasVeitas by "the Schrödinger equation" I just mean $i\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}|\psi\rangle=\hat{H}|\psi\rangle$ where $\hat{H}$ is the zero-component of the four-momentum operator. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @KrisWalker "The state evolves according to the Schrödinger equation" will become adequate as soon as someone proves that every model of QM must have exponential computational complexity.